# Perfect Grasshopper Tour

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

*Related to a [similar sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3418970/318073), here the grasshopper wants to optimize his jumps instead.*

---

**The grasshopper jumping sequences**

> We are given $n\in\mathbb N$ stones $s\in\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$, arranged in a circle.
>
> The grasshopper starts by jumping on stone $s(0)=0$ (the zeroth jump).
>
> On the $k$*th* jump, he can either jump clockwise or anticlockwise, by moving $k$ stones:
>
> $$s(k)=\begin{cases}
> (s(k-1)+k)\pmod n \\
> (s(k-1)-k)\pmod n
> \end{cases}$$
>
> He wants to make a tour: visit every stone at least once.
>
> A perfect tour would be, to visit every stone exactly once (perform exactly $n$ jumps).
>
> The question is, given $n\in\mathbb N$, in how many ways can the grasshopper make the perfect tour?

Let $a(n)$ as the number of perfect tours the grasshopper can make, given $n\in\mathbb N$.

Denote counterclockwise and clockwise jumps with $L,R$ respectively.

Without loss of generality, we can assume he starts (after zeroth jump) with either clockwise $R$ jump or counterclockwise $L$ jump: 
$$s(1)=\begin{cases}
1 &, R\text{ jump} \\
-1\equiv n-1&, L\text{ jump}
\end{cases}$$

Tours stemming from these two starting jumps, will be complements of each other (swap $L,R$ 's).

Hence, we can assume either case, and only count perfect tours that are possible from it. There will be $a_0(n)$ such perfect tours, and we can write $a(n)=2a_0(n)$. $-$ The only exception is $n=1$ which starts and ends with $k=0$ jump.

So from now on, assume $L$ is the $k=1$ jump when mentioning $a_0(n)$.

> $(Q_0)$ Can we find a closed form for $a(n)=2a_0(n)$?

If not, can we find closed forms for some special cases of $n$?

Here is the data for $n=1,\dots,85$ (brute force computation results for each such $n$):

```
a(n) = 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 8, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2, 8, 6, 16, 2, 4, 6, 8, 4, 12, 6, 16, 4, 4, 4, 16, 2, 12, 10, 32, 4, 4, 8, 8, 2, 12, 6, 16, 2, 8, 6, 24, 6, 12, 8, 32, 6, 8, 6, 8, 2, 8, 10, 32, 4, 4, 6, 24, 2, 20, 6, 64, 6, 8, 8, 8, 4, 16, 6, 16, 2, 4, 8, 24, 14, 12, 6, 32, 2, 4, 6, 16, 8,...
```

Below are my conclusions and observations so far.

**The trivial perfect tour (trivial jumping sequence)**

> We know that $a_0(n)\ge 1$ for all $n$.
>
> The trivial solution is, to alternate $\{L,R\}$ jumps, which will trivially be a perfect tour.

That is, this gives the sequence: $ s(k)=0,-1,1,-2,2,-3,3\dots$ where $-s\equiv n-s$.

**The powers of $2$**

> If $n=2^m$ is a power of two, then $a(n)=n=2^m$. $\space$Equivalently $a_0(n)=\frac{n}{2}=2^{m-1}$.

*Example:* $n=2^5=32$ has $a_0(32)=16$ such sequences: (Represent $L,R$ jumps with `_`,`#`)

```
1.   _______________________________
2.   _______________#_______________
3.   _______#_______________#_______
4.   _______#_______#_______#_______
5.   ___#_______#_______#_______#___
6.   ___#_______#___#___#_______#___
7.   ___#___#___#_______#___#___#___
8.   ___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___
9.   _#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#_
10.  _#___#___#___#_#_#___#___#___#_
11.  _#___#_#_#___#___#___#_#_#___#_
12.  _#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_
13.  _#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#_
14.  _#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_
15.  _#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
16.  _#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
```

The $\{L\}$ repeating (`1.` sequence above) is a perfect tour of $n$ $\iff$ $n$ is a power of two.

The last sequence (`16.`) is the trivial sequence that appears in every $n$.

In the above example, each row has $n-1$ characters, since we are not displaying $k=0$ jump.

**Hard perfect tours**

We say that $n$ is a hard (perfect) tour, if $a_0(n)=1$.

> $(Q_1)$ For which numbers $n\in\mathbb N$, is only the trivial tour possible? ($n$ is a hard tour?)

The first couple such numbers $n$ are (checked with brute force):

```
2, 3, 5, 9, 13, 17, 29, 37, 41, 53, 61, 73, 81,...
```

Is it possible to find sufficient and necessary conditions? (A closed form?)

So far, among first $85$ numbers, these are either primes of form $4m+1$, or $\in\{3,9,81\}$. (Beside the $n=2$ exception which is a part of the  previous case of owers of two.)

**Observations when $n$ is prime**

$1.)$ If $n=p$ is prime and of form $4m+1$, then it seems $n$ has only the trivial tour (is a hard tour).

$2.)$ If $n=p$ is prime and of form $n=4m+3$, then:

$$0\underbrace{L\dots L}_{2m+1}\underbrace{R\dots R}_{2m+1}$$

Is a perfect tour, where $0$ stands for the zeroth jump onto $s(0)=0$.

No other numbers among first $85$ numbers have this perfect tour.

Out of the first $23$ primes among first $85$ computed numbers, the prime $31$ has most perfect tours, so far. That is, it has $a_0(31)=5$ perfect tours (it has $a(31)=10$ perfect tours in total):

```
1.   _______________###############
2.   _#_#___#_###___###___#_###_#_#
3.   _#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#
4.   _#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
5.   _######_#_####_#____#_#______#
```

> $(Q_2)$ Can we find all perfect tours, in the case when $n=p$ is prime? $a_0(p)=\dots$?

**Perfect tours so far**

For the $2,\dots,85$ numbers, here are all the perfect tours, where only $s(1)=-1$ are being listed, since the other half when $s(1)=1$ represents just the complements of the first half.

```
2: 2
_

3: 2
_#

4: 4
___
_#_

5: 2
_#_#

6: 4
_#_#_
_###_

7: 4
___###
_#_#_#

8: 8
_______
___#___
_#___#_
_#_#_#_

9: 2
_#_#_#_#

10: 4
_#_#_#_#_
_#_###_#_

11: 6
_____#####
_#_#_#_#_#
_###_#___#

12: 8
_#_#___#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_
_###___###_
_###_#_###_

13: 2
_#_#_#_#_#_#

14: 8
___###_###___
___#######___
_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_###_#_#_

15: 6
_#___#_#_###_#
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_###___###___#

16: 16
_______________
_______#_______
___#_______#___
___#___#___#___
_#___#___#___#_
_#___#_#_#___#_
_#_#_#___#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_

17: 2
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#

18: 4
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_

19: 6
_________#########
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_###_#_#_#___#_#

20: 8
_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_###_#___#_###_#_
_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_

21: 4
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_###___###___###___#

22: 12
_____#####_#####_____
_____###########_____
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_
_###_#___#_#___#_###_
_###_#___###___#_###_

23: 6
___________###########
_#_#___#_#_#_#_###_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#

24: 16
_#_#___#_#___#_#___#_#_
_#_#___#_#_#_#_#___#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_###___###___###___###_
_###___###_#_###___###_
_###_#_###___###_#_###_
_###_#_###_#_###_#_###_

25: 4
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_###_#___#_###_#___#_#

26: 4
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_

27: 4
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#

28: 16
___###_###_______###_###___
___###_###___#___###_###___
___#######_______#######___
___#######___#___#######___
_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#_
_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_

29: 2
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#

30: 12
_#___#_#_###_#_#_###_#_#___#_
_#___#_#_###_###_###_#_#___#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_###___###___#_#___###___###_
_###___###___###___###___###_

31: 10
_______________###############
_#_#___#_###___###___#_###_#_#
_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_######_#_####_#____#_#______#

32: 32
_______________________________
_______________#_______________
_______#_______________#_______
_______#_______#_______#_______
___#_______#_______#_______#___
___#_______#___#___#_______#___
___#___#___#_______#___#___#___
___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___
_#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#_
_#___#___#___#_#_#___#___#___#_
_#___#_#_#___#___#___#_#_#___#_
_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_
_#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#_
_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_

33: 4
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_###___###___###___###___###___#

34: 4
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_

35: 8
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#
_#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#___#_#_#
_#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_#

36: 8
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_

37: 2
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#

38: 12
_________#########_#########_________
_________###################_________
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_
_#_###_#_#_#___#_###_#___#_#_#_###_#_

39: 6
_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_###___###___###___###___###___###___#

40: 16
_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#_
_#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#_
_#_###_#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#_###_#_
_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_

41: 2
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#

42: 8
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_###___###___###___#_#___###___###___###_
_###___###___###___###___###___###___###_

43: 6
_____________________#####################
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#

44: 24
_____#####_#####___________#####_#####_____
_____#####_#####_____#_____#####_#####_____
_____###########___________###########_____
_____###########_____#_____###########_____
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_
_###_#___#_#___#_###___###_#___#_#___#_###_
_###_#___#_#___#_###_#_###_#___#_#___#_###_
_###_#___###___#_###___###_#___###___#_###_
_###_#___###___#_###_#_###_#___###___#_###_

45: 6
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_#
_#_#_#####_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_#_#_____#_#_#

46: 12
___________###########_###########___________
___________#######################___________
_#_#___#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#___#_#_
_#_#___#_#_#_#_###_#_###_#_###_#_#_#_#___#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_

47: 8
_______________________#######################
_#_#_#___#_#___#_###___###___#_###_#_###_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#

48: 32
_#_#___#_#___#_#___#_#___#_#___#_#___#_#___#_#_
_#_#___#_#___#_#___#_#_#_#_#___#_#___#_#___#_#_
_#_#___#_#_#_#_#___#_#___#_#___#_#_#_#_#___#_#_
_#_#___#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#___#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###_
_###___###___###___###_#_###___###___###___###_
_###___###_#_###___###___###___###_#_###___###_
_###___###_#_###___###_#_###___###_#_###___###_
_###_#_###___###_#_###___###_#_###___###_#_###_
_###_#_###___###_#_###_#_###_#_###___###_#_###_
_###_#_###_#_###_#_###___###_#_###_#_###_#_###_
_###_#_###_#_###_#_###_#_###_#_###_#_###_#_###_

49: 6
___###_###___#___###_###___#___###_###___#___###
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#___#_#_#

50: 8
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_###_#___#_###_#___#_#_#_#___#_###_#___#_###_#_
_#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#_

51: 6
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#
_###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___#

52: 8
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_

53: 2
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#

54: 8
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_
_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_###_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_

55: 10
_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#
_#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_#
_###_#___###___#_###___###_#___###___#_###___###_#___#

56: 32
___###_###_______###_###_______###_###_______###_###___
___###_###_______###_###___#___###_###_______###_###___
___###_###___#___###_###_______###_###___#___###_###___
___###_###___#___###_###___#___###_###___#___###_###___
___#######_______#######_______#######_______#######___
___#######_______#######___#___#######_______#######___
___#######___#___#######_______#######___#___#######___
___#######___#___#######___#___#######___#___#######___
_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#_
_#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#_
_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_
_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_

57: 4
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___#

58: 4
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_

59: 6
_____________________________#############################
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#

60: 24
_#___#_#_###_#_#_###_#_#___#___#___#_#_###_#_#_###_#_#___#_
_#___#_#_###_#_#_###_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_###_#_#_###_#_#___#_
_#___#_#_###_###_###_#_#___#___#___#_#_###_###_###_#_#___#_
_#___#_#_###_###_###_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_###_###_###_#_#___#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_###___###___#_#___###___###___###___###___#_#___###___###_
_###___###___#_#___###___###_#_###___###___#_#___###___###_
_###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###_
_###___###___###___###___###_#_###___###___###___###___###_

61: 2
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#

62: 20
_______________###############_###############_______________
_______________###############################_______________
_#_#___#_###___###___#_###_#_#_#_#_###_#___###___###_#___#_#_
_#_#___#_###___###___#_###_#_###_#_###_#___###___###_#___#_#_
_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_
_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_###_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_######_#_####_#____#_#______#_#______#_#____#_####_#_######_
_######_#_####_#____#_#______###______#_#____#_####_#_######_

63: 6
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_#

64: 64
_______________________________________________________________
_______________________________#_______________________________
_______________#_______________________________#_______________
_______________#_______________#_______________#_______________
_______#_______________#_______________#_______________#_______
_______#_______________#_______#_______#_______________#_______
_______#_______#_______#_______________#_______#_______#_______
_______#_______#_______#_______#_______#_______#_______#_______
___#_______#_______#_______#_______#_______#_______#_______#___
___#_______#_______#_______#___#___#_______#_______#_______#___
___#_______#___#___#_______#_______#_______#___#___#_______#___
___#_______#___#___#_______#___#___#_______#___#___#_______#___
___#___#___#_______#___#___#_______#___#___#_______#___#___#___
___#___#___#_______#___#___#___#___#___#___#_______#___#___#___
___#___#___#___#___#___#___#_______#___#___#___#___#___#___#___
___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___
_#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#_
_#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#_#_#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#_
_#___#___#___#_#_#___#___#___#___#___#___#___#_#_#___#___#___#_
_#___#___#___#_#_#___#___#___#_#_#___#___#___#_#_#___#___#___#_
_#___#_#_#___#___#___#_#_#___#___#___#_#_#___#___#___#_#_#___#_
_#___#_#_#___#___#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#___#___#_#_#___#_
_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#___#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_
_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_
_#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#_
_#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#_
_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_
_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_

65: 6
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_#

66: 8
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_###___###___###___###___###___#_#___###___###___###___###___###_
_###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###_

67: 8
_________________________________#################################
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#___#_###___###___#_###_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#

68: 8
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_

69: 4
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___#

70: 16
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_
_#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#_
_#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#_
_#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_#_#_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#_
_#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#_

71: 6
___________________________________###################################
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#

72: 16
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_

73: 2
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#

74: 4
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_

75: 8
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___#

76: 24
_________#########_#########___________________#########_#########_________
_________#########_#########_________#_________#########_#########_________
_________###################___________________###################_________
_________###################_________#_________###################_________
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_
_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_###_#_
_#_###_#_#_#___#_###_#___#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#___#_###_#___#_#_#_###_#_
_#_###_#_#_#___#_###_#___#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#___#_###_#___#_#_#_###_#_

77: 14
___###_###___#___###_###___#___###_###___#___###_###___#___###_###___#___###
___#######_______#######_______#######_______#######_______#######_______###
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#___#_#_###_#_#___#_#_#
_###_#___#_#___#_###_#_###_#___#_#___#_###_#_###_#___#_#___#_###_#_###_#___#
_###_#___###___#_###___###_#___###___#_###___###_#___###___#_###___###_#___#

78: 12
_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_###___###___###___###___###___###___#_#___###___###___###___###___###___###_
_###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###_

79: 6
_______________________________________#######################################
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#

80: 32
_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#_
_#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#_
_#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#_
_#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#_
_#_###_#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#_###_#_
_#_###_#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#_###_#_
_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#___#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_
_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_###_#_

81: 2
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#

82: 4
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_

83: 6
_________________________________________#########################################
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#

84: 16
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_
_###___###___###___#_#___###___###___###___###___###___###___#_#___###___###___###_
_###___###___###___#_#___###___###___###_#_###___###___###___#_#___###___###___###_
_###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###___###_
_###___###___###___###___###___###___###_#_###___###___###___###___###___###___###_

85: 8
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_#_#_#_#_###_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#_#_#_#_#_#_#_###_#_#_#_#_#_#_#___#___#_#_#_#_#_#
_#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_###_#___#_#
```

Every natural number is a product of a power of two and some odd number $q$, hence $n=2^mq$.

It appears that $a(n)=2^ma(q)$ holds. If we prove this, this reduces the problem to odd numbers.

Additionally, recall that $a(q)=2$ when $q$ is a prime of form $4m+1$ or a power of three $3^m$. If we can prove this pattern as well, this reduces the problem to primes of form $4m+3$ and odd composite numbers other than powers of three.

> $(Q)$ Can we find (at least conjecture) closed forms $a(n)$ for some special families of numbers $n$?

For example, such as I did observe the cases of powers of $2^m,3^m$ and $p=4m+1$ primes.

Comment: in terms of a generator ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Anything that helps with the problem will be helpful and appreciated. $-$ This can include either proving existing patterns discussed in the question, or conjecturing new patterns (extending current patterns). $-$ This entire problem boils down to: find all sequences of jumps $L,R$ such that $\{s(0),s(1),s(2),\dots,s(n-1)\}$ gives a complete residue system modulo $n$.

Comment: which is all permutations of powers of a generator.