# Triangular numbers ($\text{mod } 2^n$) as a permutation of $\{0,1,2,\dots,2^n-1\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, permutations

My question is based on an observation made by [Vepir](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/318073/vepir) in their question "[Grasshopper jumping on circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3418970/121988)".

Vepir's observation was essentially that the sequence of triangle numbers $T\colon \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ $$
  T(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
forms a permutation when the inputs are restricted to
$\{0,1,\dots,2^k-1\}$ and the outputs are considered $(\text{mod } 2^k)$. *Moreover, this only works modulo powers of two.*

### Example

For example, when $k=3$, the sequence is $$
  \begin{alignat*}{8}
    n:      &&\ 0,\ & 1,\ & 2,\ & 3,\ &  4,\ &  5,\ &  6,\ &  7\\
    T(n):   &&\ 0,\ & 1,\ & 3,\ & 6,\ & 10,\ & 15,\ & 21,\ & 28\\
    T(n) \pmod {8}: &&\ 0,\ & 1,\ & 3,\ & 6,\ &  2,\ &  7,\ &  5,\ &  4
  \end{alignat*}
$$

### Question

I showed this to a colleague, and he proved it was a bijection for all $2^m$,
however, his proof involved a good deal of case analysis.

Is there a quick and easy way to see that the triangle numbers restrict to a 
permutation if and only if $k$ is a power of two?

Also, are there examples of polynomials with rational coefficients 
$f \in \mathbb Q[x]$ that restrict to a permutation if and only if $k$ is a power 
of three? A power of four? A prime number? A Fibonacci number?

Comment: Fun fact: This was [Problem 4](http://www.ommenlinea.org/wp-content/apmo/apmo1991_prb.pdf) on the 1991 Asian Pacific Math Olympiad, and reappeared as [Problem 5](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c942639_2018_mexico_national_olympiad) of the Mexican National Contest.

Comment: @URL: Interesting. But the first of those isn't actually the same problem; the teacher keeps going even if it take more than $n$ candies. The second one is indeed the same problem, since Nacho only places $n$ flags.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942790 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1928690. (The proof by Donald Knuth is on p. $947$ of [this PDF file](https://linuxnasm.be/media/pdf/donald-knuth/taocp/volume-3/taocp-vol3-sorting-searching.pdf); it's essentially the proof in my answer, without the detour through adding $\frac18$.)

Comment: This question prompted me to ask [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3491781).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll be using $\equiv$ between non-integers to denote that the two sides differ by a multiple of the modulus $b^k$.

The map is a permutation, that is, bijective, exactly if $\frac12m(m+1)\equiv\frac12n(n+1)$ implies $m=n$ for $0\le m,n\lt b^k$. So assume $\frac12m(m+1)\equiv\frac12n(n+1)$. Adding $\frac18$ yields $\frac12\left(m+\frac12\right)^2\equiv\frac12\left(n+\frac12\right)^2$. Bringing both terms to one side and factoring the difference yields $\frac12\left(m+\frac12+n+\frac12\right)\left(m+\frac12-n-\frac12\right)\equiv0$, that is, $\frac12\left(m+n+1\right)\left(m-n\right)=rb^k$.

Now if $b=2$, since $m+n+1$ and $m-n$ have different parity, at most one of them can contribute factors of $2$. Moreover, since $m,n\lt 2^k$, either factor can contain at most $k$ factors of $2$ unless $m=n$. One factor is divided out by the factor $\frac12$, so the equation cannot be fulfilled unless $m=n$.

This argument doesn't work for $b\ne2$; indeed we can always choose $m=b^k-1$ and $n=0$ to get $k$ factors of $b$ in $n+k+1$, and none of them are divided out.